# How do I take each letter or character from the text file, compare it to the KEY in the dictionary, and replace it with the VALUE?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, encryption, key

I am doing a very basic encryption/decryption program. I have been given a cipher in the form of a dictionary. All I need to do is read text from a text file, then using the dictionary, do the encryption or decryption. I thought I had this figured out, but I am having trouble.

My question: How do I take each letter or character from the text file, compare it to the KEY in the dictionary, and replace it with the VALUE?

Right now I can use Dict.get to locate the KEY, but I can not figure out how to do the encryption.

CODE:

```
def convert(inputFile, outputFile):

# Encryption and decryption are inverse of one another
CODE = {'A':')','a':'0','B':'(','b':'9','C':'*','c':'8',\
        'D':'&','d':'7','E':'^','e':'6','F':'%','f':'5',\
        'G':'$','g':'4','H':'#','h':'3','I':'@','i':'2',\
        'J':'!','j':'1','K':'Z','k':'z','L':'Y','l':'y',\
        'M':'X','m':'x','N':'W','n':'w','O':'V','o':'v',\
        'P':'U','p':'u','Q':'T','q':'t','R':'S','r':'s',\
        'S':'R','s':'r','T':'Q','t':'q','U':'P','u':'p',\
        'V':'O','v':'o','W':'N','w':'n','X':'M','x':'m',\
        'Y':'L','y':'l','Z':'K','z':'k','!':'J','1':'j',\
        '@':'I','2':'i','#':'H','3':'h','$':'G','4':'g',\
        '%':'F','5':'f','^':'E','6':'e','&':'D','7':'d',\
        '*':'C','8':'c','(':'B','9':'b',')':'A','0':'a',\
        ':':',',',':':','?':'.','.':'?','<':'>','>':'<',\
        "'":'"','"':"'",'+':'-','-':'+','=':';',';':'=',\
        '{':'[','[':'{','}':']',']':'}'}

f = open(inputFile, 'r')
result = ''
for key in f:
    result += CODE.get(key, key)
f.close()
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for key in f` loops over lines in the file, not characters. You need to loop over the characters in the line.

```
for key in f:
    result += ''.join([CODE.get(char, char) for char in key])
```

Comment: I have figured it out. Thank you for the help. I knew it was something simple I was missing.

Comment: Sorry, forgot that Python does this backwards from JS.